# Failed to write session data (files)

Tags: php, session, permissions, plesk

I just ordered a vps server by a hosting party.
It's a CentOS with Plesk 11.
So i just installed my Zend applicaton on the server but now the error log states

```
[Mon Apr 15 20:48:28 2013] [warn] [client 94.210.222.87] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Session_Exception' with message 'Zend_Session::start() - /var/www/vhosts/ontwerp.doedels.eu/httpdocs/mvc/libraries/Zend/Session.php(Line:469): Error #2 session_start(): open(/var/www/vhosts/ontwerp.doedels.eu/tmp/sess_t2orkniqjn9rsn9m84d2clsdd1, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) Array 
[Mon Apr 15 20:48:28 2013] [warn] [client 94.210.222.87] mod_fcgid: stderr: /var/www/vhosts/ontwerp.doedels.eu/httpdocs/mvc/libraries/Zend/Session.php(Line:479): Error #2 session_write_close(): open(/var/www/vhosts/ontwerp.doedels.eu/tmp/sess_t2orkniqjn9rsn9m84d2clsdd1, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) Array 
[Mon Apr 15 20:48:28 2013] [warn] [client 94.210.222.87] mod_fcgid: stderr: /var/www/vhosts/ontwerp.doedels.eu/httpdocs/mvc/libraries/Zend/Session.php(Line:479): Error #2 session_write_close(): Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/www/vhosts/ontwerp.doedels.eu/tmp) Array' in /var/www/vhosts/ontwerp.doedels.eu/httpdocs/mvc/libraries/Zend/Session.php:482
```

**What did i try so far?**
I tried setting session.save_path to {DOCUMENTROOT}/tmp and {WEBSPACEROOT}/tmp this doens't seem to work.

The phpinfo function says that session.save_path = /var/www/vhosts/ontwerp.doedels.eu/tmp    which is the good folder. The path exists and the folder has 777 CHMOD rights.

**Work around**
It seems to work when i set session.save_path = {WEBSPACEROOT}/private/sess
That is a folder i made with 777 chmod permissions, yet it doens't seems to be a permanent solution. Since i have to create this folder by every subscription i make.

**What do i know for sure?**

- The folder is not full
- The folder does exists
- The folder has writing permissions 777
- The folder owner is 0
- Running the server on fastcgi modus

Comment: "every subscription i make" - _subscription_?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need set permission for your var directory. That seems to be the problem.

Comment: Since my ftp user isn't the owner of the folder i can't. Should i do this via ssh?

Comment: Yes use ssh and I hope you have a sudo user access to change permission there.

Comment: Well yes, when i edited the permissions with SSH it worked! Thanks a lot! But do i have to do this every time i set-up a subscription?

Answer (score 3):

Default ownership may be incorrect on session folder:
Example; php-fpm7.0 on Amazon Linux defaults to apache user. If using nginx or other need to switch the folder ownership. Also as a note you have to change the user/group setting in www.conf.

```
chown -R root:nginx /var/lib/php/7.0/
sed -i 's/apache/nginx/g' /etc/php-fpm-7.0.d/www.conf
service php-fpm-7.0 restart
```

Comment: Yes, Amazon Linux is wired to be used with apache. This one did it thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Plex panel go to Software > Select PHP Version > Switch to PHP Options. Set session.save_path value to /tmp

[image: force session path plex]
found in https://flagon.digital/blog/others/failed-write-session-data#solution__defaultpath